# SharePoint Online OOTB form access denied error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, access-denied

I have a SharePoint list form which has been customized using SharePoint Designer. I am using the script to populate logged in user details in the form.

I have full control of the site and list. So when I log in everything is working as expected. But when someone with Contribute/Edit permission is trying to log in they are getting the following error:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Because of this, the user details are not populated correctly. Ideally, this should be working for anyone with contribute permission.

Can someone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var loginName = "";
        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var mgr=GetCurrentUser();
    });
    function GetCurrentUser() {
        var mgr;
        var requestUri =_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is script saved in other document library? If yes, then there might be possibility that user do not have access to script.

Comment: How you have added script to your page? Is it stored somewhere else maybe in style library/site assets? Can you please add code snippet you are using??

Comment: Please ensure the script you used that should be published. If it is not working then try to use those script code as Internally.

Comment: @PS Yes the script is in Site Assets and the user is having contribute permission to this.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have linked the script from site assets in a content editor webpart in the form. Added the sample code snippet in question.

Comment: Try to comment or remove the script and check form availability for users.

Comment: Do you have any other web part on the landing page?
Make sure this error is not thrown from any other web part on which the user is not having the permission

Comment: @GaneshSanap As you suggested I tried inserting script editor instead of content editor and it is working. I don't get why it wont work with content editor where user has access to the library.

Comment: I think other users are not having permission on code file (item level permissions??) or maybe this file is checked out to you and not published yet .

Comment: @GaneshSanap the file available is already published and shared with other users.

Answer (score 0):

Go to site settings->site permissions->check permission, check if the user have "Add and Customize Pages".

If not, edit the user permission level with "Add and Customize Pages" permission.